# Why does std::distance() for std:list<int>::iterator not return a negative number when last is before first?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, undefined-behavior, stdlist

`std::distance` is giving me a circular distance on `std::list`, not a relative distance. Why?

```
 #include <list>                                                                 
 #include <iostream>                                                             
 #include <iterator>                                                             

 using namespace std;                                                            

 int main(){                                                                     
     list<int> derp = {1,2,3,4};                                                 
     auto begin = derp.begin();                                                  
     auto end = derp.end();                                                      
     end--;                                                                      
     cout << distance(end, begin) << endl;                                       
     cout << distance(begin, end) << endl;                                       
}
```

When I run this, the following output happens:

```
2
3
```

I expect the following:

```
-3
3
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Why do you expect `3` as a result of `std::distance(begin, end)`? I would actually expect `4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior. For [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

> If `InputIt` is not [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), the behavior is undefined if `last` is not reachable from `first` by (possibly repeatedly) incrementing `first`. If `InputIt` is [*LegacyRandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), the behavior is undefined if `last` is not reachable from `first` and `first` is not reachable from `last`.

The iterator of `std::list` is not RandomAccessIterator, and its `begin` is not reachable from `end` by incrementing `end`.

Comment: Ok. Is there a std method to detect if last is reachable from first by incrementing? I'll probably just have to implement my own.

Comment: @CollinBell AFAIK there's no such methods; it's true for all the stl containers and raw array, whose `end` is reachable from `begin` by incrementing. `std::distance` doesn't perform such detection either, just left UB if not reachable.

Comment: @CollinBell You can check whether an iterator type is random access using `std::iterator_traits`, but given two arbitrary non-random access iterators that point to the same sequence, it is impossible to tell which one comes before the other, as they do not implement `operator<`. You won't be able to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

For iterators that do not meet the requirements of a [random access iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) returns the number of times `first` (the first argument) must be incremented to equal `last` (the second argument).

You are using a [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), which does not have random access iterators. In the case of `distance(end, begin)`, no matter how many times you increment `end`, it will never equal `begin`. Thus, the behaviour is undefined, and the result depends on the particulars of your standard library implementation.